# Swift collection view won't add more than 6 items?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Ok, I am having a lack of understanding with collection views here and how they continually instantiate the cells. I am adding MsStickerViews to my collection view along with the local description (the name) of that view. Ideally, I would like to do this ONLY once (not every time the user scrolls). From my understanding, the standard collection view function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

is called every time the user scrolls and will; just keep adding whatever you put in this function again and again. To get around this I created a separate class `StickerCollectionViewCell` where I have these init functions:

```
public var animalName = String()
    var logoLabel = UILabel()
    public var hasSticker = Bool(false)
public func initSticker(stickerView: MSStickerView)
    {
            print("PUTTING: ",stickerView.sticker?.localizedDescription)
            self.addSubview(stickerView)
            stickerView.startAnimating()
    }

    public func initLabels()
    {
        //print("called", animalName)
        logoLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.bounds.width, height: 100)
        logoLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        logoLabel.textAlignment = .center
        //logoLabel.text = stickerPack[indexPath.item].sticker?.localizedDescription.uppercased()
        logoLabel.text = animalName.uppercased()
        logoLabel.font = UIFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: screenSize.height * (9.8/screenSize.height))
        logoLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.width * 0.5, y: self.bounds.height * 0.96)
        self.addSubview(logoLabel)
    }
```

I then add my cells like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        // get a reference to our storyboard cell
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "stickerCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! StickerCollectionViewCell

            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear// make cell more visible in our example project

        if(cell.hasSticker == false && animalNames.contains((stickerPack[indexPath.item].sticker?.localizedDescription)!) == false)
        {
            cell.initSticker(stickerView: stickerPack[indexPath.item])
            cell.animalName = (stickerPack[indexPath.item].sticker?.localizedDescription)!
            cell.initLabels()

            animalNames.append(cell.animalName)
            cell.hasSticker = true;
        }
         print("Animal names", animalNames)

        return cell
    }
```

The reason for the if statement is I am adding my sticker views from an array of names, and until today I only had 6 names in the array. Now with 7 it started adding the last item in the array on top of another cell EVEN THOUGH I counted and it would still make 7 cells.

The bool and storing an array of the used up names has helped now they don't overlap, but the last item is never added. It does not get put into the used up names array. When I scroll around, the stickers in the cells shift around, meaning the one at the top will be at the bottom when I scroll to the bottom.

I checked and I am creating the right number of cells:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("COUNT",self.animalsAnim.count)
        return self.animalsAnim.count
    }
```

I have no idea what is causing this. How can I stop this continual refreshing of the cells? Why won't my last item in my string array get added? What is wrong?

Comment: You don't want that `if` statement. `celForRowAt` will be called whenever a cell is needed as the collectionview scrolls. You may dequeue a cell object that has been used previously. Your code needs to set all the appropriate views based on then indexpath

Answer (score 1):

Use a different/better approach.

Create a cell template in your storyboard. Set the class of the cell in the template to your custom class. Add the fields that you need to the cell, and connect them to the cell using outlets. Then get rid of all your code that adds custom fields to the cell. Simply install values into your already-added cell fields in your `cellForItemAt` method.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, never mind. This works:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()

        for view in self.subviews{
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Comment: That works, but is not very efficient. Since you already have a custom cell class, create a cell template in your storyboard, set it's class to your custom class, and add the fields that you need there. Then connect them to the custom class with outlets. Now your cells will have the fields they need as soon as they are created, and you won't be adding and removing fields from your cells every time you scroll.